# Penalty for unexplained down-votes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, down-votes

Often I come across perfectly valid questions which have been down-voted for no apparent reason, sometimes with no comments or answers at all.

I don't think a down-vote should ever be made without explaining the reason, but if you want to continue to allow it, there should at least be a penalty for doing so. We are not in the world of Franz Kafka, are we?

If the comment and down-vote are tied, then the down-vote can be reversed if the comment is deleted.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free is related.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Yes, it is related, and I read it before my post, but it seems to address all down-votes, not uncommented ones.

Comment: @Ramhound - If a comment explaining a down-vote is retracted, that implies to me that there can be no reason for the down-vote, so of course it should be reversed. If a comment remains valid after further discussion or edits, then the down-vote stands. To down-vote without a reason seems entirely contrary to the intention and spirit of the site.

Comment: @Random - I did look quite hard for previous instances this question before I posted it, but none of my searches found your link. I agree that it is the same question. Since it has already been considered and answered, I am content to withdraw it.

Comment: Eh, just leave it since other users may not use the same words in the other post

Comment: @random - Fine. Will do.

Comment: A cross-site duplicate is *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)*.